# How to get a TFS 2015 Project to show the correct build templates

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

My company uses TFS for source control. (TFVC) One rogue project decided to use GIT. They then had massive problems from training and other reasons because people didn't understand the distributed system.

With TFS 2015 you can have both a TFVC repository and a GIT repository in the same team project. So we just created a new TFVC repository and moved all the code over to it. Everything is working great but we can't get access to our XAML build templates. That way we didn't lose their SCRUM work history and all their backlog.

When we go to the build, in the template it is looking for GIT templates. I am guessing this is because the team project originally was created with a GIT repository. Is there any way we can point this to the TFVC templates like all of our other projects use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to the repository, if you create a GIT team project you can only select the GIT build definition. So does the TFVC project.

For your situation, suggest you can **place the code of your Git projects to an existing team project created with TFVC repositories**(This is **Bi-directional**). Having TFVC and Git repositories in the same team project allows you to easily access your work items, builds, and code history without switching team projects.

Detail ways please refer this MSDN blog: [TFVC and Git repositories in the same team project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/12/03/tfvc-and-git-repositories-in-the-same-team-project/)

**Note:**

- Need TFS2015 update1 and above
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 has support for team projects with both
  repo types

If you don't want to move the GIT code to a TFVC project, an alternative way would be adding a Power-Shell script in your build definition to clone the code from Git projects during the build process.